# How to create monthly value weighted returns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

| Month | Return | Marketcap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0,02 | 100 |
| 1 | 0,05 | 150 |
| 1 | 0,11 | 120 |
| 1 | -0,03 | 300 |
| 2 | 0,06 | 240 |
| 2 | -0,01 | 100 |
| 2 | -0,03 | 130 |
| 2 | 0,05 | 110 |

Hi, i have extremely large data set of monthly returns of stocks and their market cap and the question is how can i get value weighted return of portfolio that includes all stocks at specific month ( returns that is based on market cap / all market caps per month * return) so for example for month 1 I would get 100/(100+150+120+300)* 0,02 + 150/(100+150+120+300)* 0,05 ... etc until last observation of that month. The problem i find is that i have more than 300 months and 5000 different stocks with different returns and market caps.

The final output:

value weighted return for month1, value weighted return for month2 ... value weighted return month n

Not really any idea how to do this, pretty new to R or programming itself

Comment: Hello ! Please try to be more specific and read about how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can better help you. Also images of tables make it more difficult for us to help you, please post some code we can copy to create said table

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Is the sample data for one company or multiple?

Comment: Sample data is for multiple companies each month and then i will create value weighted portfolio of these companies and get value weighted return for each month

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise(
    vw_return = sum(Marketcap / sum(Marketcap) * Return)
  )

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Month vw_return
  <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1    0.0204
2     2    0.111
```

Data

```
structure(list(Month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), Return = c(0.02, 
0.05, 0.11, -0.03, 0.06, -0.01, -0.03, 0.5), Marketcap = c(100, 
150, 120, 300, 240, 100, 130, 110)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```